# caldav stopped syncing - how to fix without losing entries?

Tags: iphone, calendar, caldav

My family uses caldav in their iPhones to keep a shared calendar (yahoo) in sync with everyone.  One phone, used to add a lot of calendar entries, has stopped syncing. I tried simply reentering the PW to see if that would jump start it, but it is still "stuck".  With no diagnostic information available, I don't have a clue why.

If I "delete" this shared calendar, I will lose calendar entries added to the phone but not yet at the server.  Any suggestions?  Is there an easy way to select all calendar entries for a calendar and perhaps move them to the "local" calendar, Then I can delete the shared calendar, add it again, then move those new entries back to the shared calendar?

I wish there were some way to diagnose and fix this, I just don't think Apple has ever provided any tools for that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i dont have enough rep to comment instead. However, if you feel lucky and *really really* need your calendar events, i would try this:

1. Backup the iPhone using iTunes to your computer, make sure its a **Unencrypted** backup.
2. Navigate to ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup/
3. Look for the folder updated recently.
4. Copy that folder to the desktop.
5. Start quicklooking through some files from the copy on the desktop, you will find some events (one file is one resource, like contact, calendar event, photo etc)
6. Sort out the events you need, import them to Calendar again by double-clicking on the event (try one first, make sure you have a backup of your calendar as well)

Best of luck, its a tedious job.

Comment: I recall when I first joined stack exchange wanting to comment on someone's answer, and having to create a whole new answer until I had more rep.  Silly if you ask me.  I will give this a try, so I can see how it is all formatted in the backup.  I'm not sure about step 6, do you mean leave in the same format, just erase all the ones I don't want? It is a text file?   I'm unclear on the "double clicking" the event, not sure what program I'm to use for that step.  Of course you cannot respond with a comment of your own :-(  Or perhaps you can reply to this one?  Not sure...

Comment: Yeah, i can however comment on this. All events are file file per event, (events are in text format) it has a weird name and might need the extension .ics. But quicklook are usually able to determine what file format it is even without an extension. So just quicklook through the files and the ones that look like calendar events, try first and doubleclick or move them and add .ics on the end. If you doubleclick they usually end up in Calendar (iCal) so you can export or move them to a server using GUI instead of manhandling one file at a time.